# Serial.print slows/fails on arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have the following piece of code in my arduino loop

```
while( !Serial.available()){//wait for data to start but keep sending the distance
    distance = analogRead(A0);
    Serial.print(F("d"));
    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.print(F("|"));
    Serial.flush();
}
```

it reads from a distance sensor and sends the values to the x-bee shield I have attached to my arduino.  Here is the issue:

1. After I load a new sketch I receive data for the first minute or so - from 10-15k bytes
2. It then stops sending anything
3. If I turn the arduino off and on I *may* receive a few hundred more bytes - but not guaranteed

Besides looking at this from my own code I'm also using x-ctu's terminal to debug and seeing the same issue.  (This is also how I know the rest of my code isn't being touched as nothing is sent - interestingly when  do manually send data it is handled correctly, except it to is not sent back as it should be for debugging purposes)  Does anyone have any ideas?

I've also tried adding a delay after the writes and as you can see have scattered the `F()` macro and `Serial.flush();` everywhere I can think of with no change in the underlying issue.

---

Thanks, a few questions/comments

1. yes I want it in a while loop, the rate of sensor measurements >> than the rate of anything else.
2. doesn't the Serial.flush() make sure I don't overflow?
3. if it doesn't then I guess I'll have to play with various lengths of delay?  Is there a better way?
4. Why doesn't physically pulling the plug on my arduino/xbee "fix" the issue?  I.e. allow me to get a few k more?

In any case I'll experiment with reducing the number of measurements and see what happens later tonight

Comment: From a practical POV, why are you outputting formatted data on the serial interface? Serial communication is a relatively expensive operation, so you should minimize traffic on that channel if speed is a priority. I would simply send the raw bytes and interpret them on the other end.

Comment: What do you mean by formatted data?  The F() keyword moves things into flash memory which is larger than SRAM on an arduino.  It's probably not necessary and I will experiment with removing.

Comment: `Serial.print()` transmits the Ascii representation of `distance`. Values read by `analogRead` are between 0 and 255, making them one char long, however if you do `Serial.print(255)`, you transmit three chars: '2', '5', '5', instead of one char with ascii value 255, which is more compact.

Comment: analog read is between 0-1023  http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/analogRead.  Sending them as I get them is much simpler and I can live within that limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely sending data too quickly (hundreds of times a second) and overflowing the serial buffer and/or the xbee.

Also this line `while(!Serial.available()){//` is rather odd. You understand that it will execute in a tight loop until there is incoming data, right?

The scope of your project isn't clear so I can't suggest anything - except substituting `if` for `while` and see if that clears up the immediate issue.

Comment: have a couple of questions/comments I've added to the main question as it was too long for a comment

Comment: adding a delay(100); at the end seemed to fix the problem (I got ~60k bytes to my x-ctu before I had to leave for work). I'll run a longer test later and make 100% sure.  In the meantime it's time to make sure I read/understand the the flush command works.

Comment: @Brad - the `loop` function can run hundreds of times a second, much faster than you can send the data (same for `while`). The `delay` function could help but it's better to explicitly control the frequency through checking time - see the Arduino example "Blink without delay" for how to do this. http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay

Comment: yes thanks, I realize that. What I didn't realize was that the flush didn't solve that problem automagically (after reading a bit more about it I think I do) and I'm still confused why power cycling didn't seem to totally reset - obviously it would have failed after a few thousand more bytes, but it didn't even send a few hundred.  I wonder if the data somehow gets persisted in the arduino somewhere/how but that just seems a bit to crazy.

Comment: and thanks for the link!  I'll probably implement something similar where I throttle the checks via the baud rate.